# Tradingview Plotshape multiple conditions not working

Tags: pine-script

Please check the code - I'm not getting proper output but if I individually use the conditions its working

```
buySignal = strend == 1 and strend[1] == -1    
buyf = false    
buyf := crossover(MHULL, SHULL) and (strend == 1 and strend[1] == -1)

plotshape(buyf  ? up : na, title="UpTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, transp=0)    
plotshape(buyf  ? up : na, title="Buy", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
```

This is not working but if I just use crossover condition it is working so where am I going wrong

Comment: Are you sure this `(strend == 1 and strend[1] == -1)` condition becomes `true`?

Comment: We need the full code and a screenshot of your chart where you think it is not working.